How to change the icon in CTkInputDialog
I was making my software and just encountered an issue with CTkInputDialog. I wanted my icon on the Input Dialog, but no such attribute can help me.
I have tried to check the documentation but couldn't find any solution.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Try using CTkToplevel and adding the Input Dialog separately, then you can add an unclickable button and put your icon as the image.

What is the icon you mean? The icon on the title bar of the dialog? Or you want to add an icon inside the dialog?

I am talking about the icon on the title bar

If you want to change the icon of the title bar of CTkInputDialog, you can call .iconphoto() on the instance. But due to design issue of CustomTkinter, you need to delay the call of .iconphoto() a bit (at least 200ms), otherwise it will be override implicitly.
Below is an example:
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk

dialog = ctk.CTkInputDialog(title="Title", text="Message")
image = tk.PhotoImage(file="icon.png")
# need to delay the call .iconphoto() at least 200ms
dialog.after(250, dialog.iconphoto, False, image)
value = dialog.get_input()
print(f"{value=}")

